# How to get the first portion of a string in a uri authority (android)

Tags: android, kotlin, url, uri

I am currently working on a task and wondering how I can achieve this implementation. I have this unique URL, fake url here `https://home.ab.com` what I am trying to print out, is the first `home` after `//` not the `home` after the `.ab` let's call it company code. I know in a Uri, I can get the authority which as per documentation it returns this entire part `home.ab.com` My use case though is I only want to print out `home` based on unique companies and situation we support. How can I achieve this. This is what I have so far.

my function `getCode(uri)` now where I am trying to get `home` is where I am stuck
how can I get and return the home without the other part?

```
private fun getCode(uri: Uri): String{
   // todo
 }
```

Comment: Which `home` are you referring to? `https://home.ab.home.team/?buycode=12345678` has two `home`s.

Comment: @ArpitShukla The first home

Comment: @ArpitShukla I have updated my question, thank you.

Comment: You want the substring after 2nd slash and before first dot. Right?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes, this part ```// this [home]```

Comment: @ArpitShukla thank you in advance. This was not easy to think about.

Comment: Should I post the code? Or is the problem solved now?

Comment: @ArpitShukla I have not solved it, just saying thanks early let me see how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```kotlin
private fun getCode(uri: Uri): String{
   val s = uri.toString()
   val start = s.indexOf('/') + 2
   val end = s.indexOf('.')
   return s.substring(start, end)
}
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/fgF3rIcC6)

Answer (score 1):

Great solution @Arpit, you can make this even better with a one-liner,

```
private fun getCode(uri: Uri): String{
   return uri.host?.split(".")?.get(0) 
}
```